# c# - multicasting Socket.RecieveFrom: can port be 0

Tags: c#, sockets

Good day all

While Going through the [msdn multicasting page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.multicastoption(v=vs.110).aspx), In the "listener" part, in the code, a new ENdpoint is create using IPAddress.Any, Port=0.

The IPAddress.Any is understandable, however the port 0 confuses me. Should it not be listening on the mcastport?

```
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(mcastAddress, mcastPort);
EndPoint remoteEP = (EndPoint) new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0);   <======THIS LINE

try 
{      
    while (!done) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for multicast packets.......");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter ^C to terminate.");

        mcastSocket.ReceiveFrom(bytes, ref remoteEP);

        Console.WriteLine("Received broadcast from {0} :\n {1}\n", groupEP.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytes.Length));    
    }    
    mcastSocket.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation carefully. The initial value you give in that way, allow the function call to `ReceiveFrom` to grab packets coming in IPv4 from all remote IP addresses and ports.

If you specify a dedicate IP address or port, all other packets won't be received by the following call.